# How do green jackfruit and hearts of palm compare for vegan pulled pork/carnitas/barbecue?

Tags: substitutions, barbecue, vegan, mexican-cuisine

I have been reading a lot about the latest vegan meat substitute choices, but I'm having trouble deciding between green jackfruit and hearts of palm. I am wondering what the advantages and disadvantages of each are. Why I might prefer each?

Comment: Welcome! While what's "best" just invites opinions, something we're not big on here, comparing two options is perfectly fine, so I've edited your question a bit to focus on that.

Answer (score 4):

As a veg/vegan for 24 years, I've used both and prefer jackfruit. Hearts of palm typically come canned and quickly turn to mush if you do anything but slice them up. Whereas jackfruit has a much better, meatier consistency. I've done BBQ pulled "pork" sliders with jackfruit and they were awesome. You can buy it canned at Trader Joe's and elsewhere. Some places, like Whole Foods, sell it pre-marinated in BBQ sauce and other flavors. DELISH.

Answer (score 2):

The palm hearts I am used to (in Brazil we use *Euterpe edulis* or *Bactris gasipaes*) are generally very soft and used raw or blanched in salads. It seems too watery, and don't think that it will hold its texture as the green jackfruit does. I suggest jackfruit.

Answer (score 2):

There's a vegan place near me that makes this incredible "pulled pork sandwich" made with jackfruit and it's honestly mind-blowing. do the jack fruit.

i love all the meats, and i can say (the way they prepare it) it's just as good as pork without the greasy mouthfeel.

Answer (score 1):

The immature jack fruit is easier to get. The hearts of palm are much harder to get, hence one of the names "[millionaires salad](https://yoursourcetoday.co.uk/recipes/hearts-palm-millionaires-salad)". When we cut a coconut palm down we have two parts to the heart. The crunchy small part of about 4 kilo which is best sliced and eaten raw. The other part of the palm growing tip which is where the heart came from is made up of white leaves and these are nice to eat raw. The palm heart deteriorates fast and best used in 3 days. I have never heard of the immature/green jack fruit being eaten raw. They keep well, at least 3 days at our 28C room temperature. When peeled, chopped into lumps and cooked with meats it takes on the flavour of that meat. Here in Bali that meat is normally pork.

Comment: This is interesting information about hearts of palm, but does not answer the original question.