# Why does does vegan pulled pork specifically require jackfruit?

Tags: fruit, pork, vegan

I'd really like to try a vegan pulled pork recipe, but all of those I've come across require jackfruit. This ingredient comes from the other side of the planet, so I'd like to avoid adding it to my carbon footprint, and replace it with something more common in western Europe, with similar properties.

Can anyone tell me the reasons why those recipes use jackfruit, and if/how I can replace it?

Comment: What about seitan?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is simply because jackfruit has a consistency and texture that makes it very well suited in a substitute for pulled pork.

Apparently, you can also use [hearts of palm](https://www.simplyquinoa.com/3-ingredient-vegan-bbq-pulled-pork/), but according to [an earlier question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/84520/how-do-green-jackfruit-and-hearts-of-palm-compare-for-vegan-pulled-pork-carnitas?rq=1), it's harder to acquire and not as good as jackfruit. Here's a [mushroom-based recipe](http://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/vegan-pulled-pork-sliders/20293/). A google search for "vegan pulled pork -jackfruit" renders many more recipes without jackfruit.

In Sweden, where I live, we have [pulled pork substitutes made from soy protein](https://oumph.se/portfolios/pulled-oumph/) available in grocery stores. Perhaps something similar is available to you.